# Why use a Backward Pipe Operator instead of Function Chaining?

Tags: f#

Why use a backward pipe operator instead of a function chaining?

```
let distanceFromOrigin aPoint =
    let square x = x * x
    sqrt (square aPoint.x + square aPoint.y)
```

vs

```
let distanceFromOrigin aPoint =
    let square x = x * x
    sqrt <| square aPoint.x + square aPoint.y
```

Comment: Is it any different from Haskell's `$` operator?

Comment: It's the same definition, with a different associativity (making it a bit less useful).

Comment: http://theburningmonk.com/2011/09/fsharp-pipe-forward-and-pipe-backward/

Answer (score 35):

Because of the left associativity (`f <| g <| x` is parsed as `(f <| g) <| x` and sadly not as `f <| (g <| x)` which is equivalent to `x |> g |> f`), I found it useful only when you want to remove parentheses (instead of `f (long expression)`, you write `f <| long expression`).

Comment: +1 Yes, I think this is the main point. (I added some formatting to your answer - hope it's fine)

Answer (score 22):

Choosing between `f x`, `x |> f` and `f <| x` is mainly a question of
style. There's no absolute rule for choosing one instead of the
other. The `|>` operator is very popular, and it's a good idea to use it.

`<|` is less frequent, but if you look in the compiler's sources, you'll find a couple of
uses. For example:

```
raise <| System.InvalidOperationException (SR.GetString(SR.QillFormedAppOrLet))

if info.precision then
  failwithf "%s" <| FSComp.SR.forFormatDoesntSupportPrecision(ch.ToString())
```

`<|` is used to remove a parenthesis, and I think it make the code
more readable when used carefully. When you see it, you know the
following expression is the argument to your function. You don't
have to search for the closing parenthesis. I suggest you use it sparingly, and you should generally avoid mixing `<|` and `|>` in the same expression, as it can be very
confusing.

I sometimes enjoy using this operator to create a "block", with a
`fun` or `lazy` keyword.

```
let f (l: Lazy<_>) = ()
let g (f: _ -> _ -> _) = ()

f <| lazy
    let x = 1 + 1
    x * x

g <| fun x y ->
    let sqr n = n * n
    sqr x + sqr y
```

The block is based on indentation, so it fits quite well in F# code. Thanks
to the `<|` operator, you don't need a trailing parenthesis.

Answer (score 9):

As Scott Wlaschin pointed out [here](https://gist.github.com/swlaschin/8111200), the backward pipe operator is useful *if you need to pass in data as the first parameter (rather than the last) somewhere along a chain of pipes*. Consider the following:

```
let replace (replaceThis: string) (withThis: string) (input: string) =
    input.Replace(replaceThis, withThis)

let joinWith (input1: string) (input2: string) =
    input1 + " " + input2

let testString = "Happy"

let amendedString = testString
                    |> replace "H" "Cr"
                    |> joinWith "birthday"
```

`amendedString` is "birthday Crappy". Let's say I want it to be "Crappy birthday" instead. I can achieve that by using the backward pipe operator:

```
let amendedString = testString
                    |> replace "H" "Cr"
                    |> joinWith <| "birthday"
```

Now `amendedString` is "Crappy birthday", which is what I want.