# When executed will this be a tail call?

Tags: f#, tail-recursion, tail-call

Once compiled and ran will this behave as a tail call?

```
let rec f accu = function
   | [] -> accu
   | h::t -> (h + accu) |> f <| t
```

Maybe there is an easy way to test behavior that I'm not aware of, but that might be another question.

Comment: You can either read about tail recursion to know, or look at the compiled IL code to check if there's a `.tail` command. I'm guessing "Yes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is much easier to see if you do not use the pipelining operator. In fact, the two pipelining operators are defined as `inline`, so the compiler will simplify the code to the following (and I think this version is also more readable and simpler to understand, so I would write this):

```
let rec f accu = function
   | [] -> accu
   | h::t -> f (h + accu) t
```

Now, you can read the definition of [tail-call on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), which says:

> A tail call is a subroutine call that happens inside another procedure as its final action; it may produce a return value which is then immediately returned by the calling procedure.

So yes, the call to `f` on the last line is a tail-call.

If you wanted to analyze the original expression `(h + accu) |> f <| t` (without knowing that the pipelining operators are inlined), then this actually becomes `((h + accu) |> f) <| t`. This means that the expression calls the `<|` operator with two arguments and returns the result - so the call to `<|` is a tail call.

The `<|` operator is defined like this:

```
let (<|) f a = f a
```

Now, the call to `f` inside the pipelining operator is also a tail-call (and similarly for the other pipelining operator).

In summary, if the compiler did not do inlining, you would have a sequence of three tail-calls (compiled using the .NET `.tail` instruction to make sure that .NET performs a tail-call). However, since the compiler performs inlining, it will see that you have a recursive tail-call (`f` calling `f`) and this can be more efficiently compiled into a loop. (But calls across multiple functions or operators cannot use loops that easily.)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443865/901059), you will notice that `f <| t` is the same as `f t` (it only makes a difference if you put an expression in place of `t` which requires parenthesis).

Likewise `x |> y` is the same as `y x`.

This results in an equivalent expression which looks like this: `f (h + accu) t`,  So (assuming the compiler doesn't have a bug or some such), your function should be tail recursive and most likely will be compiled down to a loop of some sort.